# Discord.js Issue with Sending a DM to a user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get the bot to DM me whenever someone reports an issue with said bot but every time the command is run, I keep getting the following console error:

```
               user.send('An issue was reported by ' + message.author.username + ' in ' + message.channel.name + ', ' + message.guild.name + ':\n' + args[1-100]);
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\Desktop\Bot\index.js:50:18)
    at Client.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\me\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\me\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\me\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\me\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\me\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\me\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:310:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\me\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:800:20)
```

Here is my code:

```
const user = bot.users.cache.get('698238773657483344');
 case 'report':
            message.channel.bulkDelete(1);
            message.channel.send('report sent')
            console.log('An issue was reported by ' + message.author.username + ' in ' + message.channel.name + ', ' + message.guild.name + ': ' + args);

            user.send('An issue was reported by ' + message.author.username + ' in ' + message.channel.name + ', ' + message.guild.name + ':\n' + args[1-100]);
            break;
```

Note: that is not my actual user ID.

Another Note: The snippet is part of a switch loop and the const is at the top of my code, not in the loop itself

I would really appreciate if someone knew the solution to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like the aimed user isn't cached, you can use `.fetch()` [method](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=fetch) to be sure to get it in case it is not cached (If it is available in cache the bot will use cache instead)

```js
// This will fetch the user with the 698238773657483344 ID.
bot.users.fetch("698238773657483344").then(user => {
    // Up to you here to adapt to your code, at this state, if user is undefined
    // it means the ID is wrong / there is an issue while fetching.
});
```

If you only need the `user` var in your `report` case, you can do it like so :

```js
case 'report':
    bot.users.fetch("698238773657483344").then(user => {
        message.channel.bulkDelete(1);
        message.channel.send('report sent');
        console.log('An issue was reported by ' + message.author.username + ' in ' + message.channel.name + ', ' + message.guild.name + ': ' + args);

        user.send('An issue was reported by ' + message.author.username + ' in ' + message.channel.name + ', ' + message.guild.name + ':\n' + args[1-100]);
    });

    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

are you sure that bot is your client?
`const bot = new Discord.Client(options); bot.users.cache.get('698238773657483344');`

if you have client as your client try
`client.users.cache.get('id')`

Look [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client)

Comment: I did const bot = new Discord.Client();

Comment: What is in args[1-100]`? Try args[0] instead, maybe your array is null/undefined

Comment: Try console.log(user) to see if the user is valid

Comment: It says undefined

Comment: Your bot can't find a user with that userid then

Comment: I've tried it with someone else's ID as well and it still says undefined

Comment: can you console log bot.users.cache?

Answer (score 1):

Tried it on my end and it worked fine, my only guess is that that user hasn't been cached by the bot yet. Does the user of that ID share a guild with the bot? Read [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=users)

> .users - 
>   All of the User objects that have been cached at any point, mapped by their IDs

Comment: I did console.log(bot.users) and it returned that ID as being cached

Comment: Try const user = bot.users.cache.find(user => user.id === '698238773657483344');

Comment: It still says undefined. const user = bot.users.cache.find(user => user.id === '698231625657483344'); am I missing something from here?

Comment: It still says undefined when I do console.log(user)

Comment: Well, .get() returns undefined when it can't find the specified element, but since you said you did console.log(bot.users) and it is there, I'm not sure.

Comment: Should the ID be in quotes?